# Unable to read axios POST form data in express server. (Tried Using express.pasrer and body-parser)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, body-parser

I've been trying to fetch the form data sent using axios on my nodejs server. But I'm unable to.
If I send the same request back as response, then I'm able to view the data. But not on the server. I don't know why that is.
Check out my code for a better understanding of my problem.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
--other imports--
import axios from 'axios';


function Hea() {

--Hooks--

 const handleSubmit = e => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(userName + " " + passObj.userPassword + " " + passObj.userPassword2 + " " + userEmail)
    var data = {username: userName,
      password: passObj.userPassword,
      email: userEmail}
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data)
     axios.post('/register', 
         jsondata
     )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.config.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error");
      });
 }

 function checkmatch(){
--Validate function--     
 function checkmail(){
--Validate function--

  return (
 --FORM--
}

export default Hea;
```

Notice that I console the response.config.data I do get the proper results back.
Also, I've tried sending data without the JSON.stringify() and using some headers as well. But the result is the same.
This is the nodejs Code.

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mainroutes = require('./routes/mainroutes')
const cors = require('cors')


const app = express()
const port = 3763

app.use(mainroutes)
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App Running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

This is the routes.js code

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.send(`<h1>Response from server ${req} </h1>`);
    console.log(req.body , req.data, req.config);
  })
  
  module.exports = router
```

Now, for some reason, this

## Response from server ${req}

` is read properly in my react app as the response object and here i can also see the data properly. But in the server req.body , req.data, req.config result as undefined undefined undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this sending in formdata

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("username", userName);
    formData.append("password" , passObj.userPassword);
    formData.append("email" , userEmail);


axios.post('/register', formData).then(data =>
    console.log(data)
).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    return null
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In server-side, you need parse data before the calling your routes. This way, insert `app.use(mainroutes)` AFTER `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded` middlewares.